# CodeIgniter : Undefined variable get from __construct()

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm working on a project. Here's my code :

**Controller**

```
public function __construct(){
  parent::__construct();
  
  $x = $this->input->get('x');
  $this->model->val = $this->model->checkval($x);
}

public function save(){
  // some code to input to database
  echo $this->model->val;
}
```

**Model**

```
public function checkval($x){
  switch($x){
    case 1 : $y = 10; break;
    case 2 : $y = 20; break;
    case 3 : $y = 30; break;
  }
  return $y;
}
```

(That's the simple version)

> Message : Undefined variable: y
>
> Filename : models/Test_model.php

I want to access `save()`, and it will process the `$this->model->val` (`$this->model->val` has been declared as `public $val` in Model). `$this->model->val` is get from `$this->model->checkval($x)` where `$x` is get from GET method. But, it shows this error. What did I do wrong?

Comment: try `$_REQUEST['x']` in constructor

Answer (score 2):

If `$x` is not equal to 1, 2, or 3 it is never defined. To prevent this you need a default value for `$y` which then can be changed if `$x` matches one of those values:

```
public function checkval($x){
  $y = 0; // This can be false or whatever other value makes sense for your business logic
  switch($x){
    case 1 : $y = 10; break;
    case 2 : $y = 20; break;
    case 3 : $y = 30; break;
  }
  return $y;
}
```

Comment: Please  correct controller to correct it:
parent::__construct();